# fixed menu over flash chrome

Tags: css, flash, google-chrome, menu

I have a problem with the layout of a website. 
I have a fixed main menu that when you scrolling down the page the menu stands at the top.
At the sidebar I have some flash objects. When the menu is at the top of the flash objects simply disappears. 
This only happens at Chrome.

I checked the other solutions that StackOverflow provides but they cannot help.
I changed overflow hidden, the wmode from transparent to opaque, from opaque to transparent.

The site is at the development state here is the link [dev.thehellenicmail.gr](http://dev.thehellenicmail.gr)

Comment: I do not see the fixed menu? is the problem solved

Comment: @Melbourne2991 you have to scroll down to see the fixed menu

Comment: What is the div id or class? I cannot find it

Comment: @Melbourne2991 this is the html tag <nav id="access" role="navigation" class="fixedmenu">

Comment: all I see is this <nav id="access" role="navigation"> on line 273 just below `<!--CUSTOM HEADER -->`  Maybe you are looking at another version?

Comment: @Melbourne2991 check your javascript settings. When you scroll down the page, the tag obtains the class fixedmenu from jQuery script.

Comment: I am using chrome javascript is fully enabled and works on other sites.

There is a problem with your jquery code near the fixed menu part, you should have "else" not "else if"

Comment: @Melbourne2991 I've changed the else if statement to else but the script works fine in all browsers I checked... Can you try now?

Comment: I think we are looking at two different versions, I am seeing this

view-source:http://dev.thehellenicmail.gr/  On line 886 "else if" is still there

Comment: @Melbourne2991 ok check now please...

Comment: I see the `//` but still no fixed nav also `//` will comment out the entire line, not just the following word, so it will kill your script

Comment: @Melbourne2991 I killed the entire script and I added the class with the fixed menu...